# Having multiple relationships to one entity with no reverse?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I need some help here. Here is part of my data model:
[image]

I have folder, but I also want to have some folders that I can access easily without searching each time. So I made a default folders entity and I want a relationship to a certain folder.

However, it's complaining that it wants a reverse relationship. I don't see how that would work in this case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ramy's answer is correct, you don't have to define an inverse relationship. I just want to point out an alternative:

You can define *multiple inverse relationships* from `Folder` to `DefaultFolders`, e.g.

- `defAccount` as inverse relationship to `account`,
- `defArchive` as inverse relationship to `archive`,
- ... and so on.

**Disadvantage:** The `Folder` records are larger, so your database needs more space.

**Advantage:** If you define the "Delete Rule" as "Nullify" for these inverse relationships, then the `account`, `archive`, ... properties in `DefaultFolders` will be set to `nil` automatically if the corresponding `Folder` is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

In this case just ignore the warning.If the warning annoys you, add a new property in the build settings, call it MOMC_NO_INVERSE_RELATIONSHIP_WARNINGS and set the value to YES.